# Submitting a file to a sinatra backend

Tags: html, forms, file, input, sinatra

I have a form to upload a file:

```
<form action="/upload" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="image">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

and I am trying to see what is being submitted. In google chromes inspect element and when I use `params.inspect` in my back end the only form data that is submitted is `{:image => "<submitted file name>"}`. How can I get the actual image data? As per [this website](http://www.wooptoot.com/file-upload-with-sinatra) I should just recieve something in the format of:

```
{
  "image" => {
    :type => "image/png",
    :head =>  "Content-Disposition: form-data;
               name=\"myfile\";
               filename=\"cat.png\"\r\n
               Content-Type: image/png\r\n",
    :name => "myfile",
    :tempfile => #<File:/var/folders/3n/3asd/-Tmp-/RackMultipart201-1476-nfw2-0>,
    :filename=>"cat.png"
  }
}
```

I have no idea why that isn't happening. If someone can offer an explanation and correction that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to upload files you need to set the [`enctype` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-enctype) on the `form` element to `multipart/form-data`:

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```